# Jump to bottom of Integrated Terminal when running PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code to develop with PowerShell on a regular basis. I frequently will test out a single line of code by hitting <kbd>F8</kbd> (aka. *Run Selection*). However, if I've scrolled up from the bottom of the Integrated Terminal, hitting <kbd>F8</kbd> doesn't cause the Integrated Terminal to scroll down to the end of its buffer.

How can I configure VSCode, with the PowerShell Extension, to jump to the end of the Integrated Terminal buffer, when I execute the *Run Selection* command?

Comment: Semi-related, but if you use the powershell_ise, you can use `CTRL+D` to jump to the console pane and `CTRL+I` to jump to the script pane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a built-in way to do this, but you should be able to use the [macros extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros). Add the following to the end of `settings.json`:

```
"macros": {
  "PowerShellRunSelection": [
    "workbench.action.terminal.scrollToBottom",
    "PowerShell.RunSelection"
  ]
}
```

Then add a keybinding to `keybindings.json` as follows:

```
{
  "key": "f8",
  "command": "macros.PowerShellRunSelection",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'powershell'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my setting for both f5 and f8

`settings.json`

```
"macros": {
    "PowershellRunSelection": [
        "workbench.action.terminal.scrollToBottom",
        "PowerShell.RunSelection"
    ],
    "PowershellRun": [
        "workbench.action.terminal.scrollToBottom",
        "workbench.action.debug.start"
    ]
}
```

`keybindings.json`

```
{
    "key": "f8",
    "command": "macros.PowershellRunSelection",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'powershell'"
},
{
    "key": "f5",
    "command": "macros.PowershellRun",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'powershell'"
}
```